# Calling an exe from JavaScript (need to change current directory)

Tags: security, javascript

I'm calling an exe from within an html page using Javascript.
The problem is my EXE has some dependencies which are referred from current directory. Therefore, I need to change current directory to the EXEs directory, and after calling the exe it should be changed back to previous one so that nothing else is effected in later steps.

Can I also determine when the launched exe is closed so that I can set current directory back to original.

Comment: Remind me not to visit your page.

Comment: you can visit his page all you like, just don't do it in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question but you are violating the web standards by accessing client system through HTML page. I am pretty much sure you are able to do that only in damn IE using File System Object (FSO). This is absolutely not recommended to access files via Javascript/VBScript because it is a security risk. You should avoid doing that for people to consider your HTML page a good place to visit.

Comment: You are right but I'm making a web app to configure client apps, that too on our local network.